# Is this a characteristic function for some random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am aware that $\phi(t) = \cos(t) $ is the ch.f. of the random variables that takes values $\pm 1 $ with probability 1/2 each.

My question is about the following function:

$$ \phi(t) = \begin{cases} \cos(t) &\text{ if } -\pi/2 \le t \le \pi/2\cr  0 &\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases} $$

How can one conclude that this is either a ch.f. or not? I believe that a ch.f. for a discrete random variable on a lattice, this has to be periodic. If I compute the moments using my definition of $\phi(t), $ it all works, but I cannot really tell if there is some reason to say that it is not a ch.f.   Thank you for any insight.

Maurice

Comment: You might Fourier transform it and see if you get a density.

Answer (score 1):

It is not: Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\phi$ is the characteristic function of some random variable $X$. Since $\phi$ has a second derivative at $0$, $X$ has a finite second moment (see, e.g., [If the characteristics function of a random variable is differentiable even times then it has finite moment of even order](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1097296)). However, this would imply that $\phi$ is twice-differentiable globally, which is clearly not the case. Hence such an $X$ cannot exist.